# How to automatically create objects named from nested data? in R

Tags: r

There are often situations where `nest` is more useful than `list` in data analysis.
However, during analysis, I sometimes want to store individual data in objects with appropriate names in order to keep the code concise.
Therefore, I will want to create such objects in an efficient manner.
For example, look at the following code.

```r
df <- iris |>
  tidyr::nest(.by = Species)

setosa <- df[["data"]][df[["Species"]] == "setosa"][[1]]
versicolor <- df[["data"]][df[["Species"]] == "versicolor"][[1]]
virginica <- df[["data"]][df[["Species"]] == "virginica"][[1]]
```

<sup>Created on 2024-02-04 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

The objects we want to create here are `setosa` and `versicolor` and `virginica`.
Do I always have to specify this explicitly?
Is there any way to create the objects themselves automatically?

There are often situations where NEST is more useful than LIST in data analysis.
However, during analysis, I sometimes want to store individual data in objects with appropriate names in order to keep the code concise.
Therefore, I will want to create such objects in an efficient manner.
For example, look at the following code.

The objects we want to create here are `setosa` and `versicolor` and `virginica`.
Do I always have to specify this explicitly?
Is there any way to create the objects themselves recursively?

For example, the following code does not work correctly, but it is a way to take a vector of the names of the objects you want to create as arguments and create an object with that name.

```r
df$Species |> map(\(x) {
  sym(x) <- df[["data"]][df[["Species"]] == x][[1]]
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using the [`list2env()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/list2env.html) function which,

> from a named list x, create[s] an environment containing all list components as objects.

We need to set the names first with [`setNames()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/setNames.html) and ensure the environment that is assigned to is the [global environment](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/RHOME/library/base/html/environment.html).

```r
list2env(setNames(df$data, df$Species), envir = .GlobalEnv)

# Check it worked
all(
    identical(setosa, df[["data"]][df[["Species"]] == "setosa"][[1]]),
    identical(versicolor, df[["data"]][df[["Species"]] == "versicolor"][[1]]),
    identical(virginica, df[["data"]][df[["Species"]] == "virginica"][[1]])
) # TRUE
```

However, it is generally better to keep your data frames in a list than to clutter your global environment, and it makes further operations such as iteration much simpler.

Answer (score 3):

We use `split` which only needs base R and then convert the resulting named list to individual components in the global environment so that `setosa`, etc. are objects in the global environment.  That said it would usually be better to omit the last line in which case the result of the pipeline is a named list which keeps the 3 components together.  (Have incorporated use of formula as suggested by @SamR.)

```
iris |>
  split(~ Species) |>
  list2env(.GlobalEnv)
```

If it matters that the `Species` column not be in the output then

```
Split <- function(data, col, nms = setdiff(names(data), col)) {
  split(data[nms], data[[col]])
}

iris |>
  Split("Species") |>
  list2env(.GlobalEnv)
```

In all the code above, if the objects are to be placed in the current environment and that may not be the global environment then replace `.GlobalEnv` with `environment()` .

Comment: What's the advantage of your `Split()` function over `split(iris, ~Species)`? They seem to give identical output. The only thing I can think of is that formula notation wasn't supported for `split()` before R 4.1 but as you're using the base pipe this must be R >= 4.1. Incidentally, I prefer to split rather than nest generally too, but this does give slightly different output as `split()` retains the `Species` column and `nest()` drops it.

Comment: Good idea. Will update.