# Seeking simplest vectorized variable assignation process in R

Tags: r

I'm wondering if there's a simpler way to assign values to variables as character strings than using a loop and `assign()`

```
m_vars <- LETTERS[1:5]
m_values <- 1:5

for (i in seq_along(m_vars)) {
  assign(m_vars[i], m_values[i])
}
```

This works, but I'm wondering it there's a simpler way. I want to access `A`, `B`, etc **as variables directly**.

I thought maybe `setNames()` would be simpler.

```
x <- setNames(m_values, m_vars)
```

But then I have to access the value using `x["A"]` which I would like to avoid.

**EDIT ---------**

The feedback I received confirms my gut feeling that this is not the way to do it. This is how I solved the problem I had in the following function I'm using in a Shiny app (thus the input list), where I have same controls in multiple pages (thus the need for ids). Here is a play example. How would you rewrite this function following good coding standards?

```
data <- warpbreaks # preloaded in R (dataset package)
input <- list(BUD_WOOL = "A", TOT_WOOL = "B", TOT_TENSION = c("M", "L"))

do_filter <- function(id) {
  fltrs <- c("WOOL", "TENSION")
  ids <- paste(id, fltrs, sep = "_")

  for (i in seq_along(fltrs)) {
    assign(fltrs[i], input[[ids[i]]])
  }

  data |>
    filter(
      if (is.null(WOOL)) TRUE else wool == WOOL,
      if (is.null(TENSION)) TRUE else tension == TENSION
    )
}

do_filter("BUD")
do_filter("TOT")
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to automatically create objects named from nested data? in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77935438/how-to-automatically-create-objects-named-from-nested-data-in-r) - you could just do `list2env(x, envir = .GlobalEnv)`

Comment: do not, i repeat DO NOT do this. If you find yourself doing this, just know you are doing something wrong somewhere.

Comment: @Onyanbu, ok I hear you. I have edited the question to show my overall problem. What would you suggest to change?

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to do this, you could do it this way:

```
m_list <- setNames(as.list(m_values), m_vars)
list2env(m_list, envir = environment())
```

Note that the documentation for list2env states "This will be very slow for large inputs...".  I expect you have your reasons, but keeping a set of variables together in a named list, data.frame, or named vector etc. is rather neater than having lots of variable names, and reduces the risk of conflicting names.

Answer (score 0):

Typically it is preferable to create a named list rather than leave the variables loose in the global environment but assuming that you have determined that you do want them in the global environment then use `split` to create a named list and then use `list2env` .  If you do decide that a named list is ok then omit the last line.

```
split(m_values, m_vars) |>
  list2env(.GlobalEnv)
```

Note that this is similar but simpler than the solution to the problem at [How to automatically create objects named from nested data? in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77935438/how-to-automatically-create-objects-named-from-nested-data-in-r/77936366#77936366) because here we just have a vector rather than a data frame.

Comment: TI'm doing this inside a function. They are not in the global environment.

Comment: If the objects are to be placed in the current environment which is not the global environment then  replace `.GlobalEnv` with `environment()`